# Multiple webhook endpoints for an envelope

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docusignapi

I'm trying to set one endpoint for each status for the envelope ex:

```
 new EventNotification
            {
                Url = "www.myapplication.com/Created",
                
                {
                    new EnvelopeEvent { EnvelopeEventStatusCode = "Created" },
                }
            },
new EventNotification
            {
                Url = "www.myapplication.com/Delivered",
                
                {
                    new EnvelopeEvent { EnvelopeEventStatusCode = "Delivered" },
                }
            },
```

I tried to use the EventNotifications property of EnvelopeDefinition but it simply doesn't work. None of the endpoints is called when the status changes (it does work when I use the EventNotification property instead of EventNotifications).

The documentation about EventNotifications is vague, so I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read more about it in this [blog post](http://docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-add-a-connect-webhook-to-your-envelopes), but yes, EventNotification is singular, it's not an array.
You have what we call envelopeEvents which you can add more than one EventNotification too.
What you are trying to do conceptually (different endpoints for different statuses) is possible, but not needed. You get the status in the payload so you can run your code differently based on the different status.
If you still want to do that, you can add multiple EventNotification events to the EnvelopeEvents array, each with its own URL and status.

Comment: There are two different properties described in the DocuSign API documentation.The second one is literally an array of EventNotification and is called EventNotification**s**. What you mean by adding multiple event notification, the EnvelopeEvents is part of the EventNotification not the other way around.

Comment: The last sentence was supposed to be a question. I can add multiple events to a EventNotification, but I can't add multiple EventNotifications to a EnvelopeDefinition, I was hoping that the _EventNotifications_  would be the solution since it is an array of _EventNotification_

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Why do you need two different endpoints? maybe you can explain

Comment: No particular reason, except for having separate responsibilities instead of a centralized endpoint

Comment: Sorry, at this point I think you cannot do this, you would have to have a single endpoint and check the status in it.